# summernote editor - how to set codemirror default view?

Tags: codemirror, summernote

i'm use codemirror on summernote.

i want default view is codeview.

So I searched on stackoverflow and google and found some ways.

first,

```
$(".summernote").summernote({
        callbacks:{
            onInit: function(){
                $("div.note-editor button[data-event='codeview']").click();
            }
        },height: 300,
        width: '100%',
        minHeight: null,
        maxHeight: null,
        focus: true,
        placeholder: 'please, write text here!',
        lang: 'ko-KR',
        codemirror: { // codemirror options
            theme: 'blackboard',
            lineNumbers: true
        }
)};
```

However, this way does not work..

my summernote - codeview button has no [data-event='codeview'] tag.
button has class="note-btn btn btn-default btn-sm btn-codeview".

second,

```
$('.summernote').on('summernote.init', function () {
        $('.summernote').summernote('codeview.activate');
      }).summernote({
        height: 300,
        width: '100%',
        minHeight: null,
        maxHeight: null,
        focus: true,
        placeholder: 'please, write text here!',
        lang: 'ko-KR',
        codemirror: { // codemirror options
            theme: 'blackboard',
            lineNumbers: true
        }
    });
```

also does not work.

no no no,, the action is not the desired action.

When you do this, two spaces are created. Up and down.

As a result, I am using '$(".Summernote").Summernote("code",html code);' And I want the default view to be codeview.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.summernote').summernote({
    callbacks: {
        onInit: function() {
            $('.summernote').summernote('codeview.activate');
        }
    }
});
```

worked for me